# Sort by match on line in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to type what to sort by in vim? For example if I have the following:

```
    1 REPEATED_FIELDS = [
    2 'actors',
    3   'countries_of_origin',
    4 'main_details',
    5           'directors'
    6 }
```

And I want to sort lines 2-6 by and trim leading space in the sort, is there a way to do something like:

```
:2,+4:sort \(\w\)
```

On this [`sort page`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Sort_lines), I only saw the options of what lines to include/exclude in the sort, but not actually how to sort the lines themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually mentioned in `:h :sort`. You need to specify `/pattern/` followed by "r" flag.

```
2,+4sort /\w\+/r
```